# RegEx for value Range from 1 - 365

Tags: regex

What is the RegEx for value Range from 1- 365

Comment: A question of ["two problems"](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)?

Comment: Please don't ask to check for leap years on the same regex :)

Comment: For a generalization of this problem see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really a good fit for regex, but if you insist:

```
^(?:36[0-5]|3[0-5][0-9]|[12][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])$
```

This is not allowing leading zeroes. If you wish to allow those, let me know.

The expression above can be shortened a little to

```
^(?:36[0-5]|3[0-5]\d|[12]\d{2}|[1-9]\d?)$
```

but I find the first solution to be a bit more readable. YMMV.

Comment: I think you need parenthesis...this will also match `3655`

Comment: Could you please add leading zeroes?

Comment: You could use `^0*(?=[^0])(?:36[0-5]|3[0-5][0-9]|[12][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])$`

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d?|[12]\d{2}|3[0-5]\d|36[0-5])$
```

- The start anchor `^` and end anchor
  `$` are to match the whole input and
  not just part of it.
- `(? )` is for grouping.
- `|` is for alternation
- `[1-9]\d?`      matches `1` to `99`
- `[12]\d{2}`   matches `100` to `299`
- `3[0-5]\d`      matches `300` to `359`
- 36[0-5]          matches `360` to `365`

Comment: and Range from 1 -360?

Answer (score 6):

You would have to list the possible combinations 1-9, 10-99, 100-299, 300-359, 360-365:

```
^([1-9]\d?|[12]\d\d|3[0-5]\d|36[0-5])$
```

Answer (score 2):

**A general solution for matching the numbers from 1 to XYZ**

```
^(?!0)(?!\d{4}$)(?![X+1-9]\d{2}$)(?!X[Y+1-9]\d$)(?!XY[Z+1-9]$)\d+$
```

Notes:

1. If any of X, Y or Z are 9 that will make X+1 etc. be 10. If that happens the regex part that would require using the 10 should be left out.
2. This can be extended to numbers with more or less digits following the same principles.
3. It does not allow left-padding 0es.

Applied to your case:

```
^(?!0)(?!\d{4}$)(?![4-9]\d{2}$)(?!3[7-9]\d$)(?!36[6-9]$)\d+$
```

Lets explain:

```
(?!0\d*) - does not start with 0
(?!\d{4}$) - does not have 4 digits, i.e. between 1000 and infinity
(?![4-9]\d{2}$) - it's not between 400 and 999
(?!3[7-9]\d$) - it's not between 370 and 399
(?!36[6-9]$) - it's not between 366 and 369
```

[Test it.](http://rubular.com/r/4rsaWZSfVv)

Comment: All `$` signs should be removed from the regex, except the last one, or else the regex will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
^3(6[0-5]|[0-5]\d)|[12]\d\d|[1-9]\d|[1-9]$
```

Or if numbers like `05` can not be in input:

```
^3(6[0-5]|[0-5]\d)|[12]?\d?\d$
```

P.S.: Anyway no need of regex here. Use ToInt(), <=, >=

Answer (score 0):

```
^36[0-5]|(3[0-5]|[12]?[0-9])[0-9]$
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your regex engine since they may not all be PCRE-style. I usually work to the lowest common denominator unless I know it will be targeting a minimum engine.

To that end, I'd just use something like:

```
^[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-2][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9]|36[0-5]$
```

This will take care of (in order):

- `1-9`.
- `10-99`.
- `100-299`.
- `300-359`.
- `360-365`.

However, unless you're absolutely *required* to use just a regex, I wouldn't. It's like trying to kill a fly with a thermo-nuclear warhead.

Just use the much simpler `^[0-9]{1,3}$` then use whatever language features you have to convert it to an integer and check it's between 1 and 365 inclusive:

```
def isValidDayOtherThanLeapYear (s):
    if not s.matches ("^[0-9]{1,3}$"):
        return false
    n = s.toInteger()
    if n < 1 or n > 365:
        return false
    return true
```

Your code will be more readable that way and I tend to rethink the use of regular expressions the second they start looking like they may be hard to read six months down the track.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me...

^[1-3][0-6]?[0-5]?$

Comment: This will unfortunately not match all numbers between 1 and 365, for example any number containing 7, 8 or 9. The reason is that your optional ranges never go above 6. This regex will only match true for the ranges: 1-6, 10-65, 100-165, 200-265 and 300-365.