# Regex for minimum and range of number

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex for a exactly five digit number which should be in the range between 90000 – 96163.
I created a regex for exactly 5 number
@"^\d{5}$"
Now how do I make sure that it is between the range of 90000 – 96163?
Anything smaller than 90001 and over 96162 should not work.

Thanks

Comment: That's not a job for regex. Split on `-` and test each number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx for value Range from 1 - 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395811/regex-for-value-range-from-1-365)

Answer (score 2):

This is most easily achieved using a regular numeric comparison (using `<` and `>` operators) in your language.

You can do a range check using regular expressions, but it's tedious to implement and all but nicely readable. For the sake of completeness, here's a possible pattern:

```
9([0-5][0-9]{3}|6(0[0-9]{2}|1([0-5][0-9]|6[0-3])))
```

Broken up, the pattern reads as follows:

```
9                       # The first digit must be a 9
(
    [0-5][0-9]{3}       # Covering the range 90000-95999
    |
    6                   # Matching 96xxx
    (
        0[0-9]{2}       # Covering the range 96000-96099
        |
        1               # Matching 961xx
        (
            [0-5][0-9]  # Covering the range 96100-96159
            |
            6[0-3]      # Covering the range 96160-96163
        )
    )
)
```

Please don't do this if it can be avoided. Just consider what happens when the range boundaries change: Imagine you have to check whether a value is between 7243 and 132843 — not fun.

Answer (score 0):

Digit by digit:

```
/(?!^90000$)(^9([0-5]\d{3}|6(0\d{2}|1([0-5]\d|6[0-2]))))$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(9[0-5][0-9]{3}|960[0-9]{2}|961[0-5][0-9]|9616[0-3])
```

http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/

This would be enough to find a regex to find a range. No need to ask about range problems